# OpenCV 3.1 cv2.stereoCalibrate TypeError: an integer is required

Tags: python, c++, opencv, opencv3.1

Recently I managed to compile newest opencv 3.1 with cuda support.
After some tinkering I properly converted most of my python code from 2.4.x to 3.1.x wihout any problems.

But when it came time to try out the stereCalibrate capability, the error occured:

```
Exception in thread Thread-5:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "./stereo_compute.py", line 245, in calibrate
    flags)
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Here is how I call the function itself:

```
criteria = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_MAX_ITER + cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS,
    30, 1e-56)
flags = (cv2.CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO +
    cv2.CALIB_ZERO_TANGENT_DIST +
    cv2.CALIB_SAME_FOCAL_LENGTH)
(value,
self.np_calib_data['lmtx'], self.np_calib_data['ldist'],
self.np_calib_data['rmtx'], self.np_calib_data['rdist'],
self.np_calib_data['R'], self.np_calib_data['T'],
self.np_calib_data['E'], self.np_calib_data['F']
) = cv2.stereoCalibrate(
    object_points,
    l_image_points,
    r_image_points,
    (image_size[1], image_size[0],),
    self.np_calib_data['lmtx'],
    self.np_calib_data['ldist'],
    self.np_calib_data['rmtx'],
    self.np_calib_data['rdist'],
    self.np_calib_data['R'],
    self.np_calib_data['T'],
    self.np_calib_data['E'],
    self.np_calib_data['F'],
    flags,
    criteria)
```

Everything runs in a thread, that's why it's mentioned in the exception.

I can't get the correct set of parameters.

In addition the call worked for me under 2.4.x version with the same set of data.

Please help!

Comment: If I remember correctly, the last two parameters (flags and criteria) are swapped in opencv 3.1

Comment: I know, swapped them already:
[3.0-beta doc](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#stereocalibrate)

Comment: What is the sum (value fo flags) after calculating the flags?

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that with Python bindings for OpenCV, if a function has a parameter with default value, say, `None`, you often can't explicitly use this parameter with its default value. This is quite against normal Python conventions and expected behaviour.

For example, function `cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack` has parameter `blockSize` with default value `None`, so you would expect that calling

```
cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(image=img, maxCorners=10, qualityLevel=0.1, minDistance=10, mask=None, blockSize=None)
```

would be the same as

```
cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(image=img, maxCorners=10, qualityLevel=0.1, minDistance=10, mask=None)
```

but in fact, first way of using this function will result in

```
TypeError: an integer is required
```

So, with OpenCV you have to either not provide and argument, or provide correct value (and the one which is default, according to Python function/method signature, may not be correct).

You will have to check C++ sources to find actual default values.